# To remove doppler for equalizer doppler does it need decision directed like carrier recovery?

Tags: digital-communications

Normally equalizer is used at the start of the receive chain .So do we need decision directed to estimate the doppler here and also later for carrier recovery for carrier phase recovery?

Answer (score 1):

Doppler offsets are typically small fractions on the symbol rate and as such do not significantly effect the task of the equalizer which can perform under such carrier offsets. The equalized waveform is then passed through timing recovery and carrier recovery synchronization loops.

Comment: So in equalizer i am using a known pattern to estimate . Again i am using a decision directed pattern in carrier recovery. So do i need two set of patterns for equalizer and carrier recovery. Should equalizer work at more than 1 sample/symbol?

Comment: @Mike The offset from Doppler is assumed to be less than the coherence BW of the equalizer so one pattern (the target pattern) is sufficient. The feed forward equalizer should be at least 2 samples/symbol, then do timing recovery and decimate to 1 sample per symbol for the feedback filter since it is operating on the decisions